# While defining the Mandelstam variables, we take only certain 3 combinations of the momentum vectors. Why not other combintions?

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, scattering, conventions, feynman-diagrams

[image: Feynman diagram for a process]

While defining the [Mandelstam variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables) for a process, we only take these three combinations of the momentum vectors:
\begin{equation}
(p_1 + p_2)^2, (p_1 - p_3)^2, (p_1 - p_4)^2
\end{equation}
My question is, why we don't take other combinations of the momentum vectors, e.g.
\begin{equation}
(p_1 - p_2)^2, (p_1 + p_3)^2, (p_2 - p_3)^2
\end{equation}
etc.

Answer (score 2):

Because they are not independent. Expand the definitions

\begin{eqnarray}s&\equiv&(p_1+p_2)^2 = m_1^2+m_2^2+2p_1\cdot p_2\Longrightarrow 2p_1\cdot p_2=s-m_1^2-m_2^2,\\ t&\equiv&(p_1-p_3)^2=m_1^2+m_3^2-2p_1\cdot p_3\Longrightarrow 2p_1\cdot p_3=-t+m_1^2+m_3^2,\\ u&\equiv&(p_1-p_4)^2=m_1^2+m_4^2-2p_1\cdot p_4,\Longrightarrow 2p_1\cdot p_4=-u+m_1^2+m_4^2\end{eqnarray}

Then you see that $s,t,u$ are essentially equivalent to $p_1\cdot p_2$, $p_1\cdot p_3$ and $p_1\cdot p_4$. In that case your other combinations give

\begin{eqnarray}(p_1-p_2)^2&=&m_1^2+m_2^2-2p_1\cdot p_2=2m_1^2+2m_2^2-s,\\ 
(p_1+p_3)^2&=&m_1^2+m_3^2+2p_1\cdot p_3=2m_1^2+2m_2^2-t,\\ (p_1+p_4)^2&=&m_1^2+m_4^2+2p_1\cdot p_4=2m_1^2+2m_4^2-u.\end{eqnarray}